# How can I manage two different routings for a single given user in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.x

For example :

```
Router::connect(
    '/:username', 
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'),
    array('pass' => array('username'))
);
```

If the `username` parameter is prefixed by `@`, then it will redirect to a method. If not, it will redirect to different method.

Note : I'm using version 2.8

Comment: How are you planning on differentiating between a "username" and a controller?  What have you tried so far?  What have you found so far?  What hasn't worked? ...etc.  It's always good to show that you've done due diligence in looking into the topic before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Router::connect(
    '/@:username', 
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'action1'),
    array('pass' => array('username'))
);

Router::connect(
    '/:username', 
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'action2'),
    array('pass' => array('username'))
);
```

Comment: You have to switch the order though, as `/:username` will match everything.

Comment: @ndm your are right, I copied it over in the wrong order. Thanks!